# Excel - paste from another .xls file?

Tags: excel, paste

Needed to copy in some cumbersome data. Looked like it was working ok until I closed the source file (that I pasted FROM). This makes all the pasted formulas in the destination file change to #REF!

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy formulas to a new range of cells, just copy the cells containing the formulas, hit `ALT+E S F`. You can achieve the same effect by dragging the formula cell to new range.

Comment: I think the issue is copying from a different file entirely. It seems to be trying to link to the file and not working if the file isn't open in xl.